# Is $z^2 = x^2 \cos y + 1$ an orientable surface?

Tags: differential-geometry

So I can find one parametrization

$\phi (u, v) = (u, v, \sqrt{u^2 \cos v + 1})$

which only does have of it. So now I need to find another parametrization which overlaps non trivally with $\phi.$ I was thinking something like

$\psi(a,b) = (\sqrt{\frac{a^2 - 1}{\cos y}} ,b, a),$

but I have no idea if this helps me or not. Can you give me some hints??

Thanks!